# How to use arrow keys on Menu shortcuts in vb 6

Tags: vb6

Using vb6's menu editor wizard I am able to create a menu for my window easily and with shortcut keys like CTRL + A to Z keys, SHIFT + F1-F12 keys, SHIFT + CTRL + F1 -F12 keys. However I am not able use other keys e.g Arrow leys like Up, Down, Left, Right, Page Down or Page Up.

I have observed the auto generate code on my frmMenu.frm file as below:

```
Begin VB.Form frmMenu 
   Caption         =   "Form1"
   ClientHeight    =   3015
   ClientLeft      =   225
   ClientTop       =   870
   ClientWidth     =   4560
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   ScaleHeight     =   3015
   ScaleWidth      =   4560
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows Default
   Begin VB.Menu mnuProjection 
      Caption         =   "&Projection"
      Begin VB.Menu mnuArrowRight 
         Caption         =   "Arrow &Right"
      End
      Begin VB.Menu mnuArrowLeft 
         Caption         =   "Arrow &Left"
      End
      Begin VB.Menu mnuArrowUp 
         Caption         =   "Arrow &Up"
      End
      Begin VB.Menu mnuArrowDown 
         Caption         =   "Arrow &Down"
      End
      Begin VB.Menu mnuExit 
         Caption         =   "E&xit"
         Shortcut        =   ^Q
      End
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "frmMenu"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Private Sub mnuExit_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated like the code for such keys because they are lacking in the menu editor wizard

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You define `Caption - "Arrow &Right"`, but assign it a shortcut of `%{BKSP}`. Right arrow <> Backspace. Why are you pretending it is? Same question applies to every other menu item you've posted - you set the caption to something different than you set the shortcut.

Comment: I have not assigned the shortcuts because the shortcuts I want are not there

Comment: You can't, because arrows keys are reserved keys.